# Using views, how to keep details hidden until user performs filter/search

Tags: views

I created a view through which users can filter/search for users on my site based on a certain number of criteria (3).

My challenge is how to hide the results of the filter until someone performs a filter or search. At the moment, the view shows all users on my site by default. I found out making one of the filter criteria 'required' hides the users, however this prevents users from being able to filter independent of the 'required' criteria.

Thank you.

Comment: The answer to this question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46097/how-to-prevent-views-from-loading-the-results-upfront may be able to help you

Comment: @4life actually it looks like it's the same question, just differently worded.

Comment: The  second answer resolves the challenge. Apparently the "input required" option under advanced, acts differently to the "required" option under each individual filter. Thanks!